# Two appends in a single sed command

Tags: shell, sed, syntax, delimiter

Adding a new line to a text after a search keyword with `sed` is easy:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "line $i"; done |\
  sed '/line 3/a after three'
line 1
line 2
line 3
after three
line 4
line 5
```

I am used to chain search/replace commands `s` with a semikolon like

`sed 's/alpha/foo/;s/beta/bar/'`

But this does not work with the append command `a`:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "line $i"; done |\
  sed '/line 3/a after three;/line 5/a this is the end'
line 1
line 2
line 3
after three;/line 5/a this is the end
line 4
line 5
```

What is the ending delimiter of the `a` command (applies probably also to `i`)? Disclaimer: I am not interested in workarounds like piping several
`sed` commands or having multiple `-e` options on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU sed to use two scripts:

```
sed -e '/line 3/a after three' -e '/line 5/a this is the end'
```

or replace in your command `;` with a newline to end append command:

```
sed '/line 3/a after three
/line 5/a this is the end'
```

or without append. `&` contains matching part of regex:

```
sed 's/line 3/&\nafter three/;s/line 5/&\nthis is the end/'
```

Comment: Solution 1 and 3 are workarounds. I came across solution 2 myself, but I can't believe that a newline is the only possible delimiter for append and insert commands?!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed $'/line 3/a after three\n/line 5/a this is the end' file
```

This has little to do with sed but uses bash to interpret the sed command variable. In sed commands such as `a`,`c`,`i`,`r`,`R`,`w` and `W` must be ended in a newline, so this method can be used for their benefit. However, metacharacters must now be quoted i.e. `\n` becomes `\\n` so breaking the command into separate pieces is perhaps preferable i.e.

```
sed -e '/line 3/a after three' -e '/line 5/a this is the end' file
```